# Where org.reflections takes package from if i pass empty?

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, testng

i am having a problem when using reflections. I have this code in a project, which is implemented as maven dependency by other projects to find testNG test classes. So, as i haven't got a particular package, i was passing it empty and it was finding successfully classes i want when i execute locally. Here is my code:

```
    String pack = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    this.reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(pack)).setScanners(
        new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
    this.testNGTests = this.reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.testng.annotations.Test.class);
```

But i have the problem that when i execute it remotely it can't find any classes. So i was thinking that i must pass it something at package parameter. So, i want to know if any of you have and idea about that happens behind reflections when i pass empty package and why is working. Do you know something that could help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already fixed my problem. I changed the setting for package by forJavaClassPath. Thanks you! Yet, if any of you could give me some more information it will be well recieved! Regards